# Product custom attributes not displaying the Magento2 order details page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sales-order

I need to display the product custom attribute values in magento2 order details page but not display. Attributes having values in admin side.
I tried both codes.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load('4');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->getata());

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'); 
$product->get('4');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->getData());
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: yes, but code is not working in order details page

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by this way:

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

if (empty($customOptions)) { //check if product has custom options. If it doesn't go to the next product
    continue;
}

foreach($customOptions as $option) {
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { //check if option has values (Option can have values only if option type is checkbox, radio, multiselect or drop-down)
        continue;
    }

    foreach($values as $value) {
        $valueData = $value->getData(); //do whatever you want will value data
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working the above code.